# GET multiple values from URL and have them in one string

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple cms for myself where i can post articles and have them have multiple categories.

so i.e. **Article 1** has categories: ***Music*** and ***Technology***
and **Article 2** has categories ***Music*** and ***Games***

so if i go visit the ***Music*** category page i will see both Articles since they both have the category ***Music*** in them.

Now i only need to create that last part, the category page.

So whenever someone filters the categories: ***Music*** and ***Games***
it sends out the data to the URL like: `http://domain.com/categories.php?cat1=music&cat2=games`

now how would i GET those values ***music*** and ***games*** and place them in a string like: `$filter = "music games"` since those values are different every time someone filters the categories they want to see.

Someone else might filter ***Technology*** and ***Music*** then i want the string to be like: `$filter = "technology music"`

Comment: $filter = $_GET['cat1'] . ' ' . $_GET['cat2']; ? Am I missing something?

Comment: You could do `?categories[]=music&categories[]=technology` and read it like `$_GET[categories][0]` and `$_GET['categories'][1]`.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles how do i get cat3 and 4 or 5 when someone filters more than 2?

the idea is that i want to store the get values i.e. music, games, techonology inside a single string that would like: `"music games techonology"`

i can't just do $filter = $_GET['cat1'] . ' ' . $_GET['cat2']; because if someone filters a third category it will give me an error since there is no $filter = $_GET['cat3] 

i hope you can makes sense of what i just said (i am sorry english is not my first language)

Comment: Could you put all the filter string into one single string with legal separator and further tokenize them?

Comment: Or you could put ?categories=Music|Games|etc... then split the string to get the array of categories.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you would want to do something along the lines of:

```
<form action="categories.php" method="GET">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Filter Categories</legend>
    <p>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="music"/> Music</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="technology"/> Technology</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="film"/> Film</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Filter</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

When submitted, this will give you a URL such as the following:

```
http://example.com/categories.php?categories[]=music&categories[]=technology
```

Then, in the script that displays the matching entries having one of these categories, you could do the following with the `WHERE` clause:

```
$get_categories = $_GET['categories'];
$cat_clauses = array();

while ($category = array_shift($get_categories)) {
    // Clean it
    $category = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-_]/i', '', $category);

    if ($category) {
        array_push($cat_clauses, "OR category LIKE '%$category%'");
    }
}

if ($cat_clauses) {
    $cat_where = "AND (" . implode(' ', $cat_clauses) . ")";
}
```

Which might give you something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM blog
WHERE active = 1
AND (category LIKE '%technology%' OR category LIKE '%music%')
```