# How to work with arrays in html checkbox inputs and receive them as arrays in php

Tags: php, html

I need to translate a number of fields from html checkbox type but with different names, but an array of names.

And to make the form submit in php and receive arrays, and how through the values ​​received from the form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24347394/451969

Comment: This question is not written very well. You need to improve question writing skills, you need clarity in your expression!

Comment: possible duplicate of [GET multiple values from URL and have them in one string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347250/get-multiple-values-from-url-and-have-them-in-one-string)

Comment: Hi there. it's really difficult to figure out how to help you - because you are giving an overview-description. Stack Overflow works best when you give us precise, detailed technical problems you are having. Can you show us the code that you have tried yourself and tell us how it's not working for you? maybe any errors that you encountered? That way we are far more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Html:

```
value1 <input type='checkbox' name='fields[]' value='1' > <br>
value2 <input type='checkbox' name='fields[]' value='2' > <br>
value3 <input type='checkbox' name='fields[]' value='3' > <br>
valueN <input type='checkbox' name='fields[]' value='N' > <br>
```

When the submit the form, you receive these forms in php

```
<?php
$FIELDS = $_POST['fields'];

//So you access it to the selected values
for( $l=0; $l<count($FIELDS) ; $l++ )
    echo $FIELDS[$l].'\n';
?>
```